# Arduino: Setup() won't start

Tags: c++, c, class, arduino

For school I'm building a robot, which needs to be able to detect lines using 3 QRE1113 linesensors. (http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9454) I created 4 libraries, two for driving (Motor() & Driver()) they work fine. Now I created the libraries Linesensor and Eye, these are causing some trouble. When I want to use these libraries, the setup() function won't do squad. Not even turn a LED on. What seems to be the problem?

Main file:

```
#include "Motor.h"
#include "Driver.h"
#include "Lichtsensor.h"
#include "Eye.h"

Motor motor1(5, 4, true);
Motor motor2(6, 7, false);
Driver driver(motor1, motor2);
Eye eye1;

void setup(){
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("#################################################");
  Serial.println("# This sketch communicates with the arduino and #");
  Serial.println("# makes the robot drive, and react to a sensor. #");
  Serial.println("#################################################\n");
}

void loop(){
  if (eye1.getDikkeLijn() == true) {
      Serial.println("Lijn");
    }
   else {
     Serial.println("Niks");
   }
  delay(1000);
}
```

Eye library:

```
/*
Controls Lichtsensors
*/
#ifndef Eye_h
#define Eye_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Lichtsensor.h"

class Eye 
    public:
    Eye();
    Eye(Lichtsensor l1, Lichtsensor l2, Lichtsensor l3);
    boolean getDikkeLijn();
    boolean getDunneLijn();
private:
    Lichtsensor _l1;
    Lichtsensor _l2;
    Lichtsensor _l3;
};

#endif
```

And the linesensor:

```
/*
Library to get values from a light sensor
*/
#ifndef Lichtsensor_h
#define Lichtsensor_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class Lichtsensor {
public:
    Lichtsensor();
    Lichtsensor(int analogPin);
    int getCalibreerWaarde();
    int getLichtWaarde();
    boolean isDonker();
private:
    int _lichtCalibreerWaarde;
    int _analogPin;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Could this problem have to do something with the limited amount of memory on the Arduino board?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like we had too many classes and the arduino couldn't handle it anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I remember having had problems when intializing things in constructors for objects declared outside of setup(). I am not sure why, I admit not having investigated the problem. But I went with the idea that too many things were initialized before the program started.

I do not guarantee that it is the solution (and cannot really explain why), but I went around my problem by initializing things in init() methods for my objects instead of their constructors. Then I called the init() methods int my setup() after having set-up the Serial object. Something like that:

```
#include "Motor.h"
#include "Driver.h"
#include "Lichtsensor.h"
#include "Eye.h"

Motor motor1; // I do not use any more my constructor
Motor motor2; // I do not use any more my constructor
Driver driver; // I do not use any more my constructor
Eye eye1; // I do not use any more my constructor

void setup(){
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("#################################################");
    Serial.println("# This sketch communicates with the arduino and #");
    Serial.println("# makes the robot drive, and react to a sensor. #");
    Serial.println("#################################################\n");
    motor1.init(5, 4, true); // My object is initialized here
    motor2.init(6, 7, false); // My object is initialized here
    driver.init(motor1, motor2); // My object is initialized here
    eye1.init()
}
```

It is always a bit weird to construct an object in a method instead of the constructor. But as it is microcontroller programming and not a common computer program, I guess taking a more functionnal approach is sometimes the simplest.

If you do not have a better answer, you can still try that. Maybe it is enough to do that only for your Eye library as you told you had no problems with the Motor classes.

Comment: Trying this, I get the message:
error: 'class Eye' has no member named 'init'

Comment: You have to implement the init() method yourself :) For instance, create an init() method, put inside of it what is in your constructor, and remove the constructor of your class.

Comment: Ok, but do you have at least your LED switched on now with your digitalWrite(13, HIGH)? If yes, you may have an implementation problem in your Eye library. If not, I am out of ideas.

Comment: @VincentHiribarren is assuming you moved your code from the constructors to methods called init. Did you do that? Can you post all your current code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is wrong with many classes or too many things were initialized .In my case I have many classes defined by me ( more than 5 classes ) . My problem was with the way I defined the classes for example one mistake was when I defined function in the header file , in the cpp file was not prepended by the class name .In code language :

```
void begin(); // this is a function defined in the header file
void begin(){//this is in the cpp file and this is wrong definition

} 
void NameOfTheClass::begin(){ // this is the correct way in the cpp file
   //code goes here 
}
```